# How to specify the level of json.loads()?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON string to be loaded:

```
{"a": 1, "b": {"c": 123} }
```

If I use `json.loads`, it will load `{"c": 123}` as a `dict`. However, I don't want that to happen.

I want to be able to access the string directly, without interpreting the internal object in to a dict, like so:

`json_dict['b'] == '{"c": 123}'`

rather than,

`json_dict['b'] == {"c": 123}`

since the format (like spaces) and order (which will be random in a `dict`) may change and the exact string is needed to do an RSA verification.

The actual code follows:

```
r = requests.get('https://openapi.alipaydev.com/gateway.do', params)
print(r.text) 
response = json.loads(r.text)
print(response)
alipay_response = response['alipay_trade_precreate_response']
print(alipay_response['code'])
```

The output is:

```
{"alipay_trade_precreate_response":{"code":"10000","msg":"Success","out_trade_no":"123","qr_code":"https:\/\/qr.alipay.com\/bax08377e7kxveupoqnt001c"},"sign":"EqocoROqXbpkGdkFZakEkoOymGS7+UcvNi1YmcQffF4wtyQcj/RTO1sLHY8tWZFx0rxQAPjkX+7Hrszn4pNWkuBbM/c88oEbxYc+pCvnF49SHZmfkBqY6eJlLIHgPHXus5KFtvlMmkzANNHmD7c72FLDAbvMHKVyEcRPkU9ANIk="}
{'sign': 'EqocoROqXbpkGdkFZakEkoOymGS7+UcvNi1YmcQffF4wtyQcj/RTO1sLHY8tWZFx0rxQAPjkX+7Hrszn4pNWkuBbM/c88oEbxYc+pCvnF49SHZmfkBqY6eJlLIHgPHXus5KFtvlMmkzANNHmD7c72FLDAbvMHKVyEcRPkU9ANIk=', 'alipay_trade_precreate_response': {'out_trade_no': '123', 'qr_code': 'https://qr.alipay.com/bax08377e7kxveupoqnt001c', 'msg': 'Success', 'code': '10000'}}
10000
```

We can see that `response['alipay_trade_precreate_response']` is a `dict`, and the order is different from the string. I need the string so I can verify the RSA signature.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... calling `json.loads` on the JSON you shared should give you exactly what you're asking for. Can you share your code and the result?

Comment: Actually, your JSON is invalid. (It has single quotes instead of double quotes.)

Comment: @smarx: Sounds like he wants to get the raw original source of a nested object.

Comment: @SLaks In the JSON, it's a quoted string (though improperly quoted).

Comment: You should change your signature scheme to sign the entire JSON message (or encode the inner message as a string).

Comment: Once you put double quotes in there and fix the spacing to match your test, things work fine: `json.loads('{"a": 1, "b": "{\\"c\\": 123}" }')['b'] == '{"c": 123}'` is `True`

Comment: @dspjm Thanks for trying to clarify in your edit, but as I pointed out above, `json.loads` already does what you want. Please share **working** code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @dspjm I edited your question based on the actual example you gave (which has a dictionary instead of a quoted string). For that type of input, `json.loads` won't do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question: no, `json.loads` doesn't support this.

I've included two ways to accomplish your goal below. The first is very robust and relies on the lexer from [`ijson`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson/). The second method is much less robust and relies on a regular expression.

```
json_string = '{"alipay_trade_precreate_response":{"code":"10000","msg":"Success","out_trade_no":"123","qr_code":"https:\/\/qr.alipay.com\/bax08377e7kxveupoqnt001c"},"sign":"EqocoROqXbpkGdkFZakEkoOymGS7+UcvNi1YmcQffF4wtyQcj/RTO1sLHY8tWZFx0rxQAPjkX+7Hrszn4pNWkuBbM/c88oEbxYc+pCvnF49SHZmfkBqY6eJlLIHgPHXus5KFtvlMmkzANNHmD7c72FLDAbvMHKVyEcRPkU9ANIk="}'

# METHOD 1:
# ---------
import ijson
import io

def get_raw_dict_string(json_string, key='alipay_trade_precreate_response'):
    tokens = [[pos, symbol] for pos, symbol in ijson.backends.python.Lexer(io.StringIO(json_string))]
    if tokens[0][1] != '{':
        raise Exception("not a dictionary")

    start = None
    end = None
    i = 0
    level = 0
    while i < len(tokens):
        pos, symbol = tokens[i]
        if symbol == '{':
            level += 1
        elif symbol == '}':
            level -= 1
            if level == 1:
                end = pos
                break
        elif level == 1 and symbol[0] == '"':
            if ijson.backends.python.unescape(symbol[1:-1]) == key:
                if tokens[i+1][1] == ':' and tokens[i+2][1] == '{':
                    start = tokens[i+2][0]
                    i += 2
                    level += 1
        i += 1

    return json_string[start:end+1]

print(get_raw_dict_string(json_string))
# Output:
# {"code":"10000","msg":"Success","out_trade_no":"123","qr_code":"https:\/\/qr.alipay.com\/bax08377e7kxveupoqnt001c"}



# METHOD 2:
# ---------

import re
print(re.search(r'"alipay_trade_precreate_response"\s*:\s*({[^}]*})', json_string).group(1))
# Output:
# {"code":"10000","msg":"Success","out_trade_no":"123","qr_code":"https:\/\/qr.alipay.com\/bax08377e7kxveupoqnt001c"}
```